# Maintain splitted editor windows in PhpStorm

Tags: editor, phpstorm

Using PhpStorm, I usually have 2 or 3 source files opened in splitted editors. Now that I have a secondary screen, I've put all the toolbars in the second screen, and I'd like to have a fixed 3-splits layout for my editors. But as soon as I close the last tab in one of the splits, that split is gone.

I've search through PhpStorm options and surfed for an answer, but didn't seem to find how to do it.

Is there any way to fix the split layout in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get such behaviour in current version.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66407 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.